# how to search products/items on amazon on iphone?

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services

I am new to the amazon thing and I am trying to do the very basic thing i.e. the user will enter some key word for example "Madonna" and I will show the similar results that We get when we search "Madonna" at amazon on all departments.
I need the guidance i.e. which product should I subscribe to?
What will be the way to retrieve the results?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on Amazon Product advertising API, it require sign up on AWS.
http://aws.amazon.com/ 
You will find all information and source code on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html